# Appcelerator. Dynamic options dialog from array

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0.RC1 
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator that fetches tweets from twitter and inserts them into a table. For each tweet I am extracting the links (if any) and put them into a seperate array. I want to use these links (for each tweet/row) in individual options dialogs so when the user clicks a row the dialog shows up containing the links found for that tweet/row.

How can I do this? I tried to do it, but it did not work. No links are showing in the dialog.

This is my code: http://pastie.org/2003692

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Have you checked that options: `findUrls(tweet)` in line `217`
 is returning some strings?